# Endless jQuery/CSS "ticker" slider that allows for variable width content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm hunting around for an endless jQuery "ticker"/slider that will work with images of various widths.

I've tried [FlexSlider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html), and even spoken to the developers, but apparently it only works with items of a fixed width. This is a pretty common constraint, as the parent HTML element usually needs a predefined width.

I found a CSS only solution (http://jsfiddle.net/Hyg3C/4289/) but it's a bit of a hack because it only uses one very long background image (plus it jumps).

```
#images {
  background: url(http://cl.ly/9BJG/collage.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300%;
    -webkit-animation: slideshow 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:    slideshow 5s linear infinite;    

}
@-webkit-keyframes slideshow {
  0%    { left: 0; }
  100%  { left: -200%; }
}
@moz-keyframes slideshow {
  0%    { left: 0; }
  100%  { left: -200%; }
}
```

Is there a way to do this using lots of images of variable widths?

Comment: Seems to obvious to be accurate, but isn't it possible to do it with your CSS solution but instead of animating the `#images`, animating a container with all the images in it?

Comment: @RedBreast That wouldn't loop properly, but I guess it could work if I was prepared to forgo a seamless loop.

Comment: Exactly the same than the background solution as it's still one image. The idea is to have the X images in the container and reproduce this animation.

Comment: @RedBreast The background image solution obviously tiles (ie. repeats) which hides the jump. If you think you can do that with separate images, please do and I'll accept your answer!

Comment: @RedBreast This is the best I can manage using your suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/nj6xy7f0/

Comment: I was trying something with `animation-delay` and `nth-child` (included in loop later) but your last solution seems definitely better as mine is buggy (after the end of it animation, the first image starts again and override the other ones) http://jsfiddle.net/Hyg3C/4290/ If it can inspire you to optimize your last one.

Comment: @RedBreast My solution is terrible (try resizing the window). I don't think this is possible, unfortunately :(